# Trying to switch camera back to front but getting exception

Tags: android, android-camera

Trying to switch camera back to front but getting exception. cant find
 the problem Please Check and help..

> ```
> error:- 01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.vdrecord/com.vdrecord.AndroidVideoCapture}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```

**My Code:-**

```
 public class AndroidVideoCapture extends Activity{
    private static final String TAG = "CameraRecorderActivity";
  private Camera myCamera;
    private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private static String val="yes";
    private Button useOtherCamera;
  Button myButton;
  SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
  boolean recording;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        recording = false;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_video_capture);
        useOtherCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.useOtherCamera);
        useOtherCamera.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
            //Get Camera for preview
            myCamera = getCameraInstance();
        }
        });
        FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);
        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);

        if(myCamera == null){
            System.out.println("PRINT TRACK--7 ");
         Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCapture.this,
           "Fail to get Camera",
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
        }

    Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(recording){
                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object

                //Exit after saved
                finish();
   }else{

    //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
    releaseCamera();

          if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
           Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCapture.this,
             "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           finish();
          }

    mediaRecorder.start();
    recording = true;
    myButton.setText("STOP");
   }
  }};

  public int getFrontCameraId() {
      CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
      for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
          Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
          if ((val=="yes") && (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT))
          {
              val="no";
              return i;
          }

      }

      return CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK; // No front-facing camera found
  }
    public Camera getCameraInstance(){
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera c = null;
        try {
          int index = getFrontCameraId();
          if (index != -1)
          {
           c = Camera.open(index);
         //   c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }else{
             c = Camera.open(index);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
          Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
  }

  private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
     myCamera = getCameraInstance();
     mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

     myCamera.unlock();
     mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

     mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
     mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

     mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

     mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

     mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

     try {
         mediaRecorder.prepare();
     } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
         releaseMediaRecorder();
         Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
         return false;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         releaseMediaRecorder();
         Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
         return false;
     }
     return true;

  }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (myCamera != null){
            myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            myCamera = null;
        }
    }

  public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

  private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
     private Camera mCamera;

  public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
         super(context);
         mCamera = camera;

         // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
         // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
         mHolder = getHolder();
         mHolder.addCallback(this);
         // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
         mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
     }

  @Override
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
    int height) {
         // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
         // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

         if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
           // preview surface does not exist
           return;
         }

         // stop preview before making changes
         try {
             mCamera.stopPreview();

         } catch (Exception e){
           Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
           // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
         }

         // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

         // start preview with new settings
         try {
             mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
             mCamera.startPreview();

         } catch (Exception e){
           Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
         }
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
         try {
             mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
             mCamera.startPreview();
         } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
         }
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
  }
  }
```

> ```
>   Error Log:- 01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767): FATAL
>     EXCEPTION: main 01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>     ComponentInfo{com.vdrecord/com.vdrecord.AndroidVideoCapture}:
>     java.lang.NullPointerException 01-27 11:49:00.376:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(30767):   at
>     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
>     01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
>     01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127) 01-27
>     11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):  at
>     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
>     01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-27
>     11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):  at
>     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 01-27 11:49:00.376:
>     E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507) 01-27
>     11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):  at
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-27
>     11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):  at
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-27 11:49:00.376:
>     E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
>     01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747) 01-27
>     11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):  at
>     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-27 11:49:00.376:
>     E/AndroidRuntime(30767): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3158) 01-27
>     11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):  at
>     android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3145) 01-27
>     11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):  at
>     com.vdrecord.AndroidVideoCapture.onCreate(AndroidVideoCapture.java:51)
>     01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 01-27
>     11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):  at
>     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
>     01-27 11:49:00.376: E/AndroidRuntime(30767):    at
>     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to switch between front and back camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538235/unable-to-switch-between-front-and-back-camera)

Comment: 1.  Step through your code with the debugger.  If you don't know how to, then please learn.  You cannot be successful without knowing how to do this.  2.  Always post the stack trace for the exception from logcat.  If you don't know how to, then please learn.  You cannot be successful without knowing how to do this.  3.  Please don't repeat questions.  They will only be closed.

Comment: that is my post too... but i edit my code to switch but its getting error so please help...

Comment: So if you're using the debugger, where is the problem?

Comment: if i hard code to open camera either back or front its working nice but when i add  button to switch between two camera its showing error:--- java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vdrecord/com.vdrecord.AndroidVideoCapture}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It tells you exactly what line has the null-  line 51 of onCreate.  Step through with the debugger and figure out what value is null.  Then figure out why it doesn't have a value, and fix it so it does.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Still getting same error

Comment: You say that you know how to use the debugger.  You know which line causes the exception.  What are you struggling with?  If you don't know how to debug, or how to read a stack trace, please be honest and ask for help.

Answer (score 5):

Stop the camera previous instance before switching to other :

```
if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        surfaceholder.removeCallback(CameraActivity.this);
        surfaceholder = null;
}
```

And finish current camera activity, call start intent of same camera activity.

Comment: toggling front to back camera but works only once and get crashed.

Answer (score 1):

First, destroy your surface, release the camera and recreate surface manually.
Like this:

```
surfaceDestroy(holder);
surfaceCreated(holder);
surfaceChanged(holder,format,width,height);
```

It solved my problem, it may help you.